# How can an answer be selected as the correct choice on the law stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

So here is my dilemma. A lot of questions on the law stack exchange, like the practice of law itself, do not really have any answers that are better than other answers. An example is the question on whether one can be ticketed if a speed limit sign was removed. Many possible permissible answers. So how does one go about selecting the right answer if one is not knowledgable about law in the first place (because they are asking this type of question). Will that not distort the answers for others who are also not as knowledgable about the law who come here for answers? It seems a different approach might be more successful here. Perhaps there needs to be a hierarchy of answerers much like in the legal system. Any ideas here whether a) this is an issue and/or b) how to remedy it?

Comment: Hey there :) I've moved this to our Meta site, where it's been addressed in the past. Have a look at those questions and answers (particularly my answer to that first question).